# Problema ao tentar acessar meu notebook com meu Android pelo IPv4!

Tags: android, xampp, ip, emulador, wampserver

Galera, eu estou com um baita problema e ele já me deu dor de cabeça. Eu fiz uma aplicação com o Magic Software e para rodar ela no meu Android tenho que configurar o Magic Studio da maneira certa (já feito), executar o projeto no servidor do Magic (feito e funcionando) e instalar o MagicDev.apk no android (disponível na pasta do Magic XPA e já feito), sendo que ao terminar de instalar, o aplicativo deve ser rodado e ao ser executado ele pede pra digitar a URL da aplicação do Magic, que é o seguinte:
    http://[IPv4_do_notebook]/MagicScripts/DevProps.txt,
mas ao tentar acessar isso, não é possível, fala que a aplicação não foi encontrada ou falhou na conexão. Vale notar o seguinte, eu tinha esse mesmo problema de acesso quando usava o XAMPP ou o Wamp, pois ao tentar acessar o localhost com o celular, o link não respondia, ficava carregando até dar a mensagem (colocava o Wamp online para isso, claro, e mudava as configurações nos arquivos.conf). Outra coisa importante é que fiz um aplicativo para Android no Android Studio em que uma das suas funções era acessar a internet e, embora o aplicativo instalado no Android de verdade não conseguisse se conectar ao link, o emulator acessava tranquilamente (o emulator roda dentro do pc, teria algo haver?) e conseguia fazer o que tinha que fazer, sendo que esse link dava em uma página que fiz usando o Wamp, ou seja, o emulator acessava meu IP, e o celular não consegue. Minha dúvida: isso é alguma configuração do notebook, do Android, do roteador da internet ou estou fazendo algo errado? Meu amigo criou uma página usando o Wamp, o configurou certo e colocou Online e da minha casa, com o IP dele, acessava a página (com meu notebook) de forma tranquila. Mais uma observação, meu notebook se conecta à internet com Wifi e o meu Android também, ou seja, eles não estão conectados à fonte de forma direta como o meu PC da sala está, e não sei se isso também importa. Vou mais tarde tentar roda a aplicação no meu PC da sala e ver se com ele dá para acessar pelo IPv4 dele, mas creio que também não funcionará. Enfim, alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser? Não gosto de ficar mexendo nas configurações do meu notebook com relação à internet e outras coisas sem saber o que estou fazendo de fato, tenho medo de deixar meu notebook vulnerável. 
    Aqui nesse vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1njzFq07t2U dá para ver o processo que estou descrevendo aqui, mas não está funcionando para mim.
Preciso urgentemente de ajuda, por favor!!!
Andei pesquisando nos fóruns em inglês e vi que talvez possa ser culpa do firewall. Alguém sabe?

Answer (score 0):

Galera, já descobri, era culpa do firewall mesmo. Quando desliguei tudo funcionou como o esperado. Não posso ficar com ele desligado por questões de segurança, mas pelo que vi dá para configurá-lo para aceitar só o meu celular.
Não entendo o motivo dos votos negativos para minha pergunta, já que acho pertinente e pelo que vi, ninguém conseguiu responder, muito obrigado por isso. Votaram contra, mas esses bonitos não responderam nada, então criem vergonha na cara, seus gênios!!!!